# Неиспользуемый конструктор: неправильная архитектура?

Tags: javascript

Сейчас структура кода примерно следующая:

```
function A() {
    this.UI = {
        Bar: new A.UI.Bar(this._element),
    };

    for (let element in this.UI) {
        this.UI[element].draw();
    }
};

A.UI = function() {
    // ? *
};

A.UI.prototype = {
    draw: function() {
        //
    }
};

A.UI.Bar = function() {
    this._parent = arguments[0];
};

A.UI.Bar.prototype = {
    __proto__: A.UI.prototype,

    build: function() {
        //
    },
};
```

Вопрос об `A.UI = function() {}`. Эта функция является конструктором. Но объектов этого класса создаваться не будет. То есть в данном виде функция никогда не используется, а является необходимой лишь для того, чтобы можно было определить прототип этого класса, который будет содержать общие методы (в частности, `A.UI.Bar`, `A.UI.Foo` должны иметь доступ к ним (что и определяется в строке с `__proto__`)).

Чувствую, что таким код оставлять нельзя. Что делать? Наследовать `A.UI.Bar` и `A.UI.Foo` (пока в коде нет, говорю о нем для примера) от какого-то простого объекта, внутри которого содержатся необходимые методы? Но с другой стороны у `A.UI` в дальнейшем могут появиться какие-то статические свойства, к которым нужен будет доступ (кстати, сейчас из прототипа `A.UI.prototype` доступ к свойствам, объявленным в "конструкторе" получить невозможно, но хотелось бы иметь возможность). Или же такая структура приемлема и ее можно оставлять?

В общем говоря, вопрос о пустых (неиспользуемых) конструкторах, которые нужны только для определения прототипа (который уже будет использоваться).

Comment: ерунда написана, с неверной реализацией наследования и сваливанием всего в одну кучу

Comment: @Grundy неверной реализацией наследования именно в том, о чем я спрашивал? Или вообще?

Comment: @ smellyshovel, вообще.

Comment: @Grundy а можно поподробнее? Я ж научиться хочу :) Это вы так из-за A.UI.Bar=function-подобных вещей?

Comment: и это, и вот это: `A.UI.Bar.prototype = {
    __proto__: A.UI.prototype,`

Comment: @Grundy а что здесь не так? Вроде приводят подобные примеры...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65551/discussion-between-grundy-and-smellyshovel).